# One problem of NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

the code is:

```
 typedef struct _Package 
{
    char* data;
    int dataLen;
}Package;

Package *pack=(Package *)malloc(sizeof(pack));
pack->dataLen = 10;
pack->data = (char *)malloc(10);
strcpy(pack->data,"hellohello");

NSMutableArray *lstPack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[lstPack addobjec:pack];
```

**when the program goto [lstPack addobject:pack],it cann't go on.
If you know the reason，please tell me。**

Thank you！

Comment: You've got undefined behaviour there, because you allocate 10 chars for `data`, but actually you copy 11 (`"hellohello"` is 11 characters when you include the terminating null character). Also, I have provided the reason below why your code is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to obj-c containters (including NSMutableArray) only obj-c objects. To add a c-structure to array you can wrap it to NSValue object:

```
[lstPack addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:pack]];
```

Later you access stored value:

```
Package* pack = (Package*)[[lstPack objectAtIndex:i] pointerValue];
```

Note also that you possibly have a typo in that line - method name is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you very much!
[lstPack addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:pack]] is correct.
But when I use  Package *p = (Package *)[lstPack objectAtIndex:0]; to get the pack, the result is that the p->data is nil.How can I get    
it correct?

Answer (score 0):

“… the result is that the p->data is nil …” — perhaps because of `pack->dataLen = (char *)malloc(10);`
I think, you wanted to do `pack->data = (char *)malloc(10);` instead?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `CFMutableArray` instead which can handle arrays of arbitrary objects, and you can use it as you would an `NSMutableArray` (for the most part).

```
// create the array
NSMutableArray *lstPack = (NSMutableArray *) CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, 0, NULL);

// add an item
[lstPack addObject:pack];

// get an item
Pack *anObject = (Pack *) [lstPack objectAtIndex:0];    

// don't forget to release
// (because we obtained it from a function with "Create" in its name)
[lstPack release];
```

The parameters to [`CFArrayCreateMutable`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableArrayRef/Reference/reference.html) are:

1. The allocator to use for the array. Providing `NULL` here means to use the default allocator.
2. The limit on the size of the array. 0 means that there is no limit, any other integer means that the array is only created to hold exactly that many items or less.
3. The last parameter is a pointer to a structure containing function pointers. More info can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFArrayRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CFArrayCallBacks). By providing `NULL` here, it means that you don't want the array to do anything with the values that you give it. Ordinarily for an `NSMutableArray`, it would `retain` objects that are added to it and `release` objects that are removed from it¹, but a `CFMutableArray` created with no callbacks will not do this.

¹ The reason that your code is failing is because the `NSMutableArray` is trying to send `retain` to your `Pack` struct, but of course, it is not an Objective-C object, so it bombs out.